# Error: JUnit command line test classes inside the jar

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have searched SO for this question but all I found was how to run JUnit from command line on a single file.

I have a small Javaproject which I created using maven. This project has my JUnit test calsses, suites and test runner.

I compiled the project using maven and got a jar file of the project called `cs.jar`.

The tests run fine when I use maven from eclipse or from maven command line.

Now I have to pass this `cs.jar` to my colleague who does not have maven on his machine, so I thought I will send him the `junit.jar` and my `cs.jar` so that he can run the test cases and see the results.

He uses windows machine and I sent him instruction to run the JUnit from command line using this syntax:

```
java -cp cs.jar;junit.jar;hamcrest-core.jar org.runner.JUnitCore com.abc.cs.test.run.CSTestRunner
```

However I get the message -

```
JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: com.abc.cs.test.run.CSTestRunner
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: The two classes (command line and error message) don't match, do you think that is the problem?

Comment: @Matthew -No that is not the problem. I had manually edited the package names to give an example. It was typo mistake. My package names are correct in the actual code.

Comment: do a jar -tvf cs.jar and make sure that the class is in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your project with Maven it is kind enough to *exclude test classes from the packaged jar*. This is normal behavior, and nice; you do your tests when you build and then get a nice lightweight jar.

If you want to package your test classes with your jar (not recommended for production use) you can see [Maven's solution](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html#How_to_create_a_jar_containing_test_classes).

However, the real solution is to get your buddy on the Maven bandwagon ;)